# LFS 7.8 - Pass1 GCC 5.2.0 error in 'make'

Tags: make, gcc, lfs

I am working on LFS 7.8.

In Pass1 GCC 5.2.0 compilation there is an error in 'make' :

```
configure: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/libvtv':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libvtv] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Host system is CentOS 7 with GCC version 4.8.5

Attached Config.log
[config.log](https://www100.zippyshare.com/v/uNaPF7ZU/file.html)

Comment: Do you have **g++** installed?

Comment: Did you run `version-check.sh` on your host (CentOS) as described in *Preface > Host System Requirements*? Can you update you question and add results printed by this script?

Comment: yes g++ is installed and version-check.sh on host was also ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally problem is solved with --disable-libvtv in configure command of gcc and then run make and make install.